# Program like JMeter to measure transactions per second over Java socket?

Tags: java, performance, sockets, optimization

I'm trying to measure the number of transactions per second my server can handle. Previously I was using Apache JMeter to see what using a REST based approach would yield. Now I would like to see what kind of performance I can expect if clients simply send their requests via a socket connection. I'm wondering if there is a program out there that can act as the client and perform the measurements like JMeter would.

It would be nice if this testing program could start up some given number of threads to simulate multiple clients. Obviously I would also need the client to be able to take in some specified binary data that would be sent over the socket.

Comment: What's the meaning of a "transaction" in the context of a socket?

Comment: Sorry, that's the nomenclature around here. Round trip time. From the time the client sends a request to the time it gets a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use JMeter with the [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler)